# BC331 and BC541?

Tags: transistors

I tried to find datasheets for **BC331** and **BC541** to compare them with [BC547](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BC/BC547.pdf).

Can I replace **BC331** / **BC541** with **BC547**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BC331
NPN, 60v, 30 mA, hFE= 125, Ft = 100 MHz, TI, low noise, TO92
 Very old and tired.

[Some data here](http://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=22940)

[Related selection guide here](http://alltransistors.com/crsearch.php?mat=Si&struct=npn&pc=0.25&ucb=60V&uce=60V&ueb=6V&ic=0.03&tj=150%C2%B0C&ft=100MHz&cc=6&hfe=125MIN&mnf=&caps=TO92)

BC541: Does not seem to be a known device.

---

A BC547 will be a good substitute for most older silicon NPN transistors.
 Note that BC541 = 60V rated and BC547 = 50V. This is extremely unlikely to cause a problem.

For most small signal transistor purposes I use and recommend the following:

BC337-40  NPN through hole [Datasheet here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BC337-D.PDF)
 BC327-40 PNP through hole  [Datasheet here](http://61.222.192.61/mccsemi/up_pdf/BC327~328%28TO-92%29.PDF)
 BC807-40  PNP SMD [Datasheet here](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BC/BC807.pdf)
 BC815-40 NPN SMD [Datasheet here](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BC/BC817.pdf)

All 45V, typically 0.8A (varies slightly with manufacturer), TO92 or SOT23
 Ft = 100 Mhz
 Hfe (current gain = 250-600, mean = 400.

All these are often available as cheaply as any other transistor available (look around) and have abpout as good a combination of current, current gain and general usefulness as anyhing else going. When you find better cheaper please advise.